# Agda list last of a generic list of naturals concatenated with a list of 1

Tags: list, agda, vec

I have the function:

```
natListLast : List ℕ → ℕ
natListLast []            = 0
natListLast nats@(x ∷ xs) = v.last (v.fromList nats)
```

When I do

```
_ : natListLast (2 l.∷ l.[] l.++ 1 l.∷ l.[]) ≡ 1
_ = refl
```

I don't get any error.

But when I try to generalize this to an arbitrary `List nat` like so:

```
natListConcatLast : (nats : List ℕ) → natListLast (nats l.++ 1 l.∷ l.[]) ≡ 1
natListConcatLast [] = refl
natListConcatLast nats@(x ∷ xs) = ?
```

I'm not sure what to replace `?` with.

I tried starting with `begin`:

```
natListConcatLast : (nats : List ℕ) → natListLast (nats l.++ 1 l.∷ l.[]) ≡ 1
natListConcatLast [] = refl
natListConcatLast nats@(x ∷ xs) =
  begin
    natListLast (nats l.++ 1 l.∷ l.[])
  ≡⟨⟩
    v.last (v.fromList ((x l.∷ xs) l.++ 1 l.∷ l.[]))
  ≡⟨⟩
    ?
  ≡⟨⟩
    1
  ∎
```

but I get this error:

```
1 !=
(last (fromList ((x List.∷ xs) l.++ 1 List.∷ List.[]))
 | initLast (fromList ((x List.∷ xs) l.++ 1 List.∷ List.[])))
of type ℕ
when checking that the expression 1 ∎ has type
last (fromList ((x List.∷ xs) l.++ 1 List.∷ List.[])) ≡ 1
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error. I'm not sure how to deal with `| initLast`.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any good reason for wanting to define `natListLast` via `Data.Vec.last` instead of writing it directly?

Comment: I needed it because I was getting the error `l.foldr (λ _ → suc) 0 (nats l.++ 1 List.∷ List.[]) != suc _n_199 of
type ℕ
when checking that the expression
fromList (nats l.++ 1 List.∷ l.[]) has type Vec ℕ (1 + _n_199)` if I used `v.last (v.fromList <...>))` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following solution:

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_ ; refl)

natListLast : List ℕ → ℕ
natListLast [] = 0
natListLast (x ∷ []) = x
natListLast (_ ∷ y ∷ l) = natListLast (y ∷ l)

natListConcatLast : ∀ l → natListLast (l ++ [ 1 ]) ≡ 1
natListConcatLast [] = refl
natListConcatLast (_ ∷ []) = refl
natListConcatLast (_ ∷ _ ∷ l) = natListConcatLast (_ ∷ l)
```